# python find text in a string from a csv

Tags: python, string, csv, find

I open a csv file that is an output form a windows CMD command.

I read the csv and assigne a variable, but I can find any word even I'm seeing it.

IT seems to be enconde...

content of output.txt (
Host Name:                 hostname

**OS Name:**                   Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard

OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393

OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation)

```
f = open("output.txt", "rt")
f = f.read()
print(f.find("OS Name"))
```

OUTPUT

<class 'str'>

-1

Comment: What does `print(f)` show?

Comment: Maybe this can be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308872/check-whether-string-is-in-csv or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765087/search-for-string-in-csv-files-using-python-and-write-the-results

Comment: @StevenRumbalski print the file exactly. I see the word in the file but It seems to be binary or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
f = open("output.txt", "rt", encoding='utf-8')
f = f.read()
print(f.find("OS Name"))
```

The code above returns `21` corresponding to the position of the first occurence of the value `"OS Name"` while `print(f.find("random_value"))` returns `-1` since `"random_value"` does not exist in the text file.